# echo out valuename in php

Tags: php, variables, echo

how can I print out a variable name in text in php?

I want to accomplish something as simple as having this:

```
echo "|" . "$myvariable" . "|";
```

print out this:

```
|$myvariable|
```

instead of this:

`||`

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `"\$myvariable"` you can escape characters with special meaning with a backslash.

Comment: just `echo '|$myvariable|';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes so that the variables don't get interpolated:

```
echo "|" . '$myvariable' . "|";
```

Comment: Thank you, that made life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score -3):

As others pointed out, use single quotes to show the variable name "as is".

```
echo "|" . '$myvariable' . "|";
```

Be sure to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) part of the manual.